# Tapestry 5 : 2 dependent select fields using zone

Tags: java, select, drop-down-menu, tapestry, zone

As I never worked on a tapestry project, this issue might seem dumb to some of you. 
Anyway, I really need help for this.

What I want to do is the following:
I have a first dropdown list for example :

- Numbers
- Letters
- Special Chars

And a second dropdown list which content depends on the value selected in the first list.
For Numbers we should have a list of numbers from 0 to 9.
For Letters, a list of letters from A to Z.
And for Special Chars, a list of special characters (e.g: *,/+$%).

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example from the jumpstart for tapestry:
http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/selectdependency1

It covers everything you need in your scenario.